# Type mismatch error while passing function result to sub

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have this procedure and function, where within the function I check if the sheet name is matching the initial array of names (indicated as data typed in by the user in excel section 'rng_Target').

The error occurs at this line of the function :

```
If element = valueToFind Then
```

when it checks if element of the array is equal ws.Name. I believe its the problem with declaration of the variable type but tried changing it multiple time and cannot get it right. Please help!

```
Sub AdjustTableSize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim specificNames As Variant
    Dim name As Variant
    
    myArray = Range("rng_Target").Value
    
    ' Set the specific sheet names
    specificNames = Array(myArray()) ' Add your specific sheet names here
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Check if the worksheet name is in the specificNames array
        If IsInArray(ws.name, specificNames) Then
            ' Set the table on the sheet (assuming there is only one table per sheet)
            Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
            
            ' Get the last row with data in the table
            lastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
            
            ' Check if there is any data in the table
            If lastRow > 1 Then
                ' Delete the rows below the last row with data in the table
                tbl.Range.Resize(lastRow).Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

' Function to check if a value is in an array
Function IsInArray(valueToFind As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valueToFind Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Tried to change Variant to String as ws.Name result will be string however this will tell me within the function check that 'element' and 'valueToFind' have to be of Variant or Object type.

Comment: If I manually fill `specificNames` with strings, your code works. I think the error is in `AdjustTableSize()` and not in `IsInArray()` but I don't know what is in `rng_Target`, `myArray` or `specificNames`.  Try adding `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module - it will force you to explicitly declare all variables, so you don't get any errors because of different variable types.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray` is a two-dimensional array as you read it from a range.

Then you put `myArray` as first element into an one-dimensional array --> `specificNames = Array(myArray())`

When you read from this array the first element is the two-dimensional `myArray` which can't be compared to a string value.

Pass `myArray` to `isInArray` and change the function like this:

```vb
Function isInArray(valueToFind As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) = valueToFind Then
            isInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    isInArray = False
End Function
```

Like this the `For`-loop checks a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to look at my query however I am still receiving error on If arr(i, 1) = valueToFind Then

Comment: Thank you for looking into it @ike, however I still get an error on If arr(i, 1) = valueToFind Then

Answer (score 0):

- The problem of the code is how to assign value to `specificNames`. Both below code lines work well.

```vb
specificNames = Range("rng_Target").Value
' OR
specificNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
```

```
Option Explicit

Sub AdjustTableSize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim specificNames As Variant
    ' Set the specific sheet names
    'specificNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3") ' Add your specific sheet names here
    specificNames = Range("rng_Target").Value
    ' Loop through each worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Check if the worksheet name is in the specificNames array
        If IsInArray(ws.name, specificNames) Then
            Debug.Print "Found " & ws.name
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not found " & ws.name
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
' Function to check if a value is in an array
Function IsInArray(ByVal valueToFind As Variant, ByVal arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valueToFind Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```

---

Let's talk about following code lines:

```vb
myArray = Range("rng_Target").Value
specificNames = Array(myArray)  ' w/o inner ()
```

- Assumes `rng_Target` is a named range A1:A2
- The contents of cells: A1 / Sheet1, A2 / Sheet2
- The value of `myArray` is as below

```vb
 myArray(1)(1) : "Sheet1"
 myArray(2)(1) : "Sheet2"
```

- `specificNames` will be a nested array. The value of `specificNames` is as below.

```vb
 specificNames(0)(1,1) : "Sheet1"
 specificNames(0)(2,1) : "Sheet2"
```

- In `IsInArray()`, argument `arr` (a nested array) is same as `specificNames`. `element` in `For` loop will be an array. It is no way to compare an array with a string. That is the reason of type mismatch error.

```vb
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valueToFind Then
```

- Add a nested `For` loop to make it work. The purpose of the snippet is just for you to understand the nested array.

```vb
' Remember to modify [specificNames = Array(myArray)] in Sub AdjustTableSize() before testing

Function IsInArray(valueToFind As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant, ele As Variant
    For Each element In arr
        For Each ele In element
            If ele = valueToFind Then
                IsInArray = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next element
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```